# Do global variables take longer fetch time?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The below code works fine for attached input.

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        return wordBreakMemo(s, new HashSet<>(wordDict), 0, new Boolean[s.length()]);
    }

    private boolean wordBreakMemo(String s, Set<String> wordDict, int start, Boolean[] memo) {
        if (start == s.length()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (memo[start] != null) {
            return memo[start];
        }
        for (int end = start + 1; end <= s.length(); end++) {
            if (wordDict.contains(s.substring(start, end)) && wordBreakMemo(s, wordDict, end, memo)) {
                return memo[start] = true;
            }
        }
        return memo[start] = false;
    }
}
```

But when I change the local variables to global as below, my code take longer to execute, resulting in 'Time Limit Exceeded' on LeetCode.

```
class Solution {
    HashSet<String> set;
    String s;
    Boolean dp[];
    public boolean wordBreak(String s, List<String> wordDict) {
        
        set=new HashSet();
        set.addAll(wordDict);
        this.s=s;
        dp=new Boolean[s.length()];
        return wordMemo(0);
    }
    public boolean wordMemo(int start)
    {
        if(start==s.length())
            return true;
        
        if(dp[start]!=null)
            return dp[start];
        
        for(int i=start+1; i<=s.length(); i++)
        {
            if(set.contains(s.substring(start, i)) && wordMemo(i))
            {
                dp[start]=true;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab"
["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa"]
```

Can someone please explain what is happening around here?

Comment: Also if you compare two blocks of code then try not to rename everything its very hard to follow this way.

Comment: Access modifiers does matter especially the `final` keyword. `private final HashSet<String> set;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables don't have slower fetch times, no.

Whenever you get Time Limit Exceeded in a coding challenge you should assume you have a a flawed or buggy algorithm or data structure. It's never micro factors like fetch times or access modifiers or the language you've chosen. Even if you could speed up your program 10% with better memory access patterns or 100% by switching from Python to C, you're probably off by 10,000% or 10,000,000%, not 100%. That's how bad it can be when your program is accidentally O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(2<sup>n</sup>) when the challenge designers expect O(n).

Here, the first program has:

```
return memo[start] = false;
```

While the second one has just:

```
return false;
```

It never memoizes `false` results. There are a lot more repeated computations, enough to kill the algorithm's Big-O time complexity.

Comment: The second version of his code should imho be faster because he doesn't use the stack that much

Comment: That's exactly the kind of micro factor I'm talking about. A few less variables on the stack might yield a tiny speedup, yet that's irrelevant if broken memoization turns what should be a linear time algorithm into an exponential one.

Comment: Uhm yes and no, if he doesn't use the stack that much it will take much longer to get a stack overflow. But you found the main bug.

Comment: Whether you're concerned about speed or about the risk of stack overflow (which is not the same thing), my response is the same. If you have recursive code that uses O(n) stack space you can't prevent stack overflow by reducing how many function arguments you use. You need to change to an O(1) space algorithm so the stack usage doesn't grow the larger the inputs are. Lowering number of variables lowers the multiplier--maybe you go from 4n to 2n stack usage. That's still O(n). It's an important skill not to waste one's energy on the wrong kinds of optimizations.